# bc: does POSIX prohibit standalone use of relational operators?

Tags: posix, bc

I want to compare two numbers with `bc`. Per this [highly rated answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31087503/8798391), I can do it in a manner as such:

```
printf '%s\n' '1.2 > 0.4' | bc
```

`bc` sends `1` to STDOUT, indicating that the statement is true (it would have returned 0 if the statement was false).

[Per the POSIX page for `bc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html):

> Unlike all other operators, the relational operators ( '<', '>', "<=", ">=", "==", "!=" ) shall be only valid as the object of an if, while, or inside a for statement.

Perhaps I am misinterpreting, but this language seems to disallow the syntax used in the above example.

Is standalone use of relational operators in `bc` a violation of POSIX? If so, how should I rewrite my example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Perhaps I am misinterpreting, but this language seems to disallow the syntax used in the above example.

That example assumes GNU bc, which adds its own extensions to the bc language. As documented in its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_chapter/bc_1.html#SEC3), you should use the `-s` switch to make it process the exact POSIX bc language, or the `-w` switch if you want it to warn about extensions:

```
$ echo '1.2 > 0.4' | bc -s
(standard_in) 2: Error: comparison in expression
$ echo '1.2 > 0.4' | bc -w
(standard_in) 2: (Warning) comparison in expression
1
$ echo '1.2 > 0.4' | bc
1
```

> If so, how should I rewrite my example?

```
$ printf 'if(%s > %s){a=1};a\n' 1.2 0.4 | bc -s
1
```

thanks @icarus for the shorter, easier on the eyes version.

Comment: golfing a bit `printf 'if(%s > %s){a=1};a\n' 1.2 1.4 | bc -s`

Comment: seems like a very stupid rule in posix bc, wonder why that rule exists. and the workarounds one have to do to stay posix compliant is evidently not pretty.

Comment: @hanshenrik maybe the designers preferred `1 < 5 < 4` to be an error, rather than produce unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Vaelus sure comparing a bool to a number could produce an error, i wouldn't mind, but that's not what's happening with `1.2 > 0.4`

Comment: @hanshenrik but there is no bool type (no user-visible one, at least). GNU bc allows boolean expressions, converts them to `0` and `1`, and has control structures like `if` test for non-zero, which permits type-confusion. POSIX bc simply forbids boolean *values* from coming into existence unless they're immediately consumed by a control structure, which avoids any chance of type-confusion without adding the complexity of actual declared types to the language.

Comment: @hanshenrik (of course the reality is probably somewhere between this and the fact that POSIX was just standardizing an existing implementation of bc which had a rather simplistic parser... POSIX bc doesn't even have "and", "or", or "not" operations.)

Comment: A bit of history for you: this rule mostly exists because `bc` used to be implemented as a frontend to `dc`, which used to only have those operators when conditionally executing macros.

Comment: @hanshenrik you shouldn't over-analyze it; it's not the only irksome limitation -- there are many others, some because of its `dc` backend, and some because of the incomplete parser (1-letter names, no `else`, no  empty statements if `for(;;)`, obligatory parens with `return`, etc). Unlike `awk`, which went through the new-awk (`nawk`) iteration which fixed much of the early ineptness and turned it into a useful language (POSIX awk is based on `nawk`), there was no commonly implemented new-bc to standardize upon, so they had to freeze a stunted version of it.